# DynamicProperty vs MutableProperty vs AnyProperty vs ConstantsProperty

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

What's difference between them? Could you give me an example of in which scenario I should use dynamic/mutable/any/constants property?

Answer (score 7):

All your answer are in this link [Property.swift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/v4.2.2/ReactiveCocoa/Swift/Property.swift)

I give you some examples:

```
let privatString = MutableProperty<String>("PrivatString")
    // AnyProperty are only for observing. You can't change it with observableProperty.value
    let observableProperty: AnyProperty = AnyProperty<String>(privatString)

    print(observableProperty)

    // ConstantProperty describes observable constant value.
    let constantProperty = ConstantProperty<String>("ConstantString")
    //  constantProperty.value = "" Error

    // Thread safe observable mutable property. It's value is changable
    let mutableProperty = MutableProperty<String>("mutableProperty")
    mutableProperty.value = "New mutable property value"

    // DynamicProperty uses KVO. 
    let dynamicProperty = DynamicProperty(object: self.view.layer, keyPath: "bounds")
    dynamicProperty.producer.startWithNext { frame in
        let frame = frame as! NSValue
        let rect = frame.CGRectValue()
        print(rect)
    }
```